# Photoshop Multiple Layer Masks

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I link two layer masks together?

I'm trying to create a divider bar in Photoshop, that fades out at each end (see picture).

[image]

As you can see, I have it fading out at the bottom. How can I do the same to the top?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply two layer masks, just put one on the layer in question and then put the layer in a Group. Then apply the other layer mask to the Group. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this using a single layer mask and using either:

- the reflected gradient tool (easiest) or
- the linear gradient tool in transparent mode used twice (useful if you want different fade for top and bottom).